# How can I disable the EJB Timer in Wildfly 8?

Tags: timer, configuration, ejb, wildfly

I have 2 instances running independently and using the same database. I want to run the timer on one instance and disable on another instance. What should i do to achieve?

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be the case that the timer service is clustered and the jobs run on any instance but only once, synchronized via the DB?

Answer (score 1):

I have also tried to configure my batch to run only on one instance. Unfortunately, I am not aware of a way to explicitely disable the batch on certain nodes.

But as shi [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362744/how-can-i-disable-the-ejb-timer-in-wildfly-8#comment45068113_28362744), it is possible to keep you batch processes on all instances and synchronize them via DB which has e.g. the failover advantage. However, for EJB timer this is available only in Widfly 9 (see [the issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-283)).

I solved it by using **Quartz Scheduler** in [clustered configuration](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering) which uses an approach very similar to the clustered EJB timers.